# Is installing applications on a network drive going to make them slow?

Tags: network-shares, portable

I have installed a few portable apps onto my network drive at work. Are they going to run noticeably slower than if I store them locally?

Comment: There is always going to be dependent on some factors and it might be slightly slower, but there is no really definitive answer and as this could result in argumentative answers I'm voting to close it. You should run actual profiling software to evaluate whether it slows down your work...

Comment: You may find this of interest, "NAS vs eSATA vs USB vs Firewire vs 10/100/1000"
http://www.pcqanda.com/dc/dcboard.php?az=show_topic&forum=2&topic_id=526550 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on how much they need to access the disk, for example a browser caches files on it's harddisk and that would take longer on a network drive.

It really depends on how much the program writes to/reads from the harddisk. Startup might also be slower, for the same reason.